# Literature on the theory of photon counting

Tags: optics, photons, resource-recommendations

I am looking for literature on the **theory of photon counting**. In case the term is not clear as is, this should involve stuff like Mandel's photon counting formula, generalizations thereof, different models for physical detectors (e.g. with finite efficiency, spatial extent etc.), relation to field correlation functions, etc.

What I have found so far:

- The most extensive account I've seen is in **Gardiner & Zoller *Quantum Noise***. There is a quite detailed chapter on the topic. It is, however, based on rather old literature (mostly [Srinivas & Davies 1980](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/713820643)). I would be curious about more recent perspectives.
- **Garrison & Chiao *Quantum Optics*** has a whole chapter with a useful overview of different devices and references to more recent literature. It is also rather detailed. What confuses me is how disjoint the methodology is from Gardiner & Zoller's account. E.g. Mandel's counting formula and the references surrounding it are not even mentioned.
- I've checked a few other books (Cohen-Tannoudji, Breuer&Pettrucione, Agarwal, Loudon, Barnett & Radmore), but most of them seem to only feature minor detours into the topic, if anything. Google also didn't help much, it either leads me to detector companies or stuff on basic Glauber correlation theory.

Any recent reviews on the topic, overviews of the literature or individual papers to track the citation ladder would be very helpful!

Comment: found this recent  experimental work https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/20/12/3475

Answer (score 2):

I would try Mandel and Wolf, "Optical Coherence and Quantum Optics."  There are many discussions of photon counting experiments and the theory behind it all.

Comment: thanks a lot & +1! I took some time to look at the relevant chapters... not sure how I missed it, Mandel&Wolf seems to indeed be the standard book on this topic. A few of the things I was looking for are discussed there, but also some still missing. I'll keep searching!

Comment: @Wolfpertinger What is missing?

Comment: mostly the relation to the stuff on detector feedback they have in Gardiner&Zoller, but I am also looking for discussions of specific modern devices (as they have to some extent in Garrison&Chiao), which probably did not even exist back when the book was published.